# Removing spaces from data while searching in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a plugin for bootstrap table (https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) by wenzhixin. I have a data filter column option set to true. One of my column data contains data such as "45 E1". When I try to search by inserting "45E" in the input box, I am not getting any results.

It would be really helpful if someone could provide any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide your own search function via the `customSearch` option then …?

Comment: Is there any way i could do it in the same function?

Comment: What “same function”?

Comment: I mean the same "initSearch" function in filter-control.js

Comment: You should not modify source files of external plugins/libraries directly, that’s just going to cause trouble when those get updated. That is _why_ ways to interfere with the normal logic using such callbacks exist.

Comment: Ok. I will try with customSearch option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the customSearch function provided by the plugin and replace the space while checking.

Comment: Is there any way i could do it by modifying filter-control.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set trimOnSearch false this in the table options.